# How can I ensure only one instance of a script is running at a time?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Suppose I launch a powershell script and it's running in a loop.
I open a second ps console and launch a second script. In this script I want to detect if the first script is running or not. 
What are the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking at opening 2 separate consoles, you'll need to add some logic in your script to do some changes to the file system, registry or even the title bar of your PowerShell session where it is running.  Then you can use some logic in your 2nd console to look for that information.

One other method, that I typically use, is with WMI:

```
PS>get-wmiobject win32_process|where {$_.name -eq "powershell.exe"}|select-exp commandline
```

An example:

```
CommandLine                : powershell.exe -file "./loop.ps1"
```

This means that you need to call powershell.exe to run your script though.

Comment: @dotdot - yeah, since you have the CLR available in both processes, a mutex is cleaner than using old school file locks (or equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

When only interested in processes on my local  computer, I would use

```
get-process *powershell*
```

I want to get PowerShell ISE too, therefore the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same and wrote a [module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SingleInstance/1.1.0) that uses a mutex to restrict script invocation to a single instance. To use it, you call the `Enter-SingleInstance` function that returns `true` if this is the first script instance invoking it or `false` if it is not the first instance (by default, it uses the script path to identify the script instance, but you can use a custom identifier, such as GUID). At the end, you need to call `Exit-SingleInstance` to release the mutex, e.g.:

```
if (!(Enter-SingleInstance)) {
    throw "The script is already running."
}
else {
    try {
        # Do what you need to do.
    }
    finally {
        # Make sure you exit single instance on both success and failure.
        Exit-SingleInstance
    }
}
```